# Get all users by role using Parse's PHP SDK

Tags: php, parse-platform

This should be a simple task but I can't find a solution. I use Parse and I have a few users and some roles defined. Every user is referenced by a role, so when I go in the Roles list I see the users assigned to each role. The question is: how can I get all users that have a specific role, using PHP SDK?

I tried this:

```
$query = new ParseQuery("_Role");
$query->equalTo('name', 'admin');
$adminRole = $query->first();
$users = $adminRole->getUsers();
```

Actually, `$users` will contain a ParseRelation object (the relation between roles and users) but I can't find in the result the list of the users assigned to the admin role.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

**Sergui, this is your code :**

```
$query = new ParseQuery("_Role");
$query->equalTo('name', 'admin');
$adminRole = $query->find();
$users = $adminRole->getUsers();`
```

**Here is an edit that might fix your issue :**

```
$query = new ParseQuery("_Role");
$query->equalTo('name', 'admin');
$adminRole = $query->find();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($adminRole); $i++) {
     $adminObject = $adminRole[$i];
     $users = $adminObject->get('users');
     // Here you do the actual fetching of the data
     $users->fetch
     //Then do whatever you want with the data
     //e.g
     $username = $users->get("username");
     //$username being some random global variable.
   }
```

Parse stated in their documentation(at the 'Objects' pane towards the end of the relational data section) that:

> **By default, when fetching an object, related ParseObjects are not fetched. These objects' values cannot be retrieved until they have been fetched.**

Hence the use of the `$users->fetch`.
I hope this helps, even if this post is about 3 months now.